# Convert string representation of array to Apex Array

Tags: apex, json, list, array

*Edited to correct JSON string

I have a string which looks like: "[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]]"

I need to convert it to Apex array like: [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]]

Using JavaScript I am able to simply pass string to JSON.parse() to get desired result.  Is there an Apex equivalent?  I have looked into Apex JSON class but have been unsuccessful so far.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This does not parse with JSON since you have values like "1 2" and "3 4" in the markup. This would parse in both JavaScript JSON and with the Apex JSON parser if updated to "[[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]]" for example.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for the reply, I have corrected the JSON string above (I mistakenly left out the commas when typing the question). Now then, how to use Apex to convert to array?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Added**

As its clear that there are 3 levels of strings, you can simple use `JSON.deserialize` :

```
System.debug(JSON.deserialize('[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]]',List<List<List<String>>>.Class));
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I could have written a comment but I wanted to paste a screenshot and so writing Answer.

This is not a valid JSON: `"[[[1 2],[3 4],[5 6]]]"`

As you said you tested using JSON parse in JS:

[image]

Comment: I have corrected the JSON string above (I mistakenly left out the commas when typing the question). Now then, how to use Apex to convert to array?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Pls mark the answer solved if solved